# Printing to Thermal Printer (Without Margins & Padding)

Tags: css, printing, thermal-printer

I have a Star SP700 Cutter Thermal Printer. I am using Internet Explorer to Print Labels. It does what I need, however its always adding TOP and BOTTOM margins/padding for every single label. I did the Page Setup in IE and removed all margins, Removed Header and Footer Setting, however I am still seeing the Space above and Below my text....this is how it prints...

```
---------------------------

My Text

---------------------------
```

However I want it to print like this...

```
----------------------------
My Text
----------------------------
```

It looks normal within IE, however When I print then it adds margins.

Here is my HTML.

```
<style>
html, body{
    padding:0mm;
    margin:0mm;
    font-family:Arial;

}
    #main {
        width:47mm;
        height:5mm;
        border:solid 0.1mm #000000;
    }
    </style>
<body>

    <div id="main">

    <div>Hello Friend</div>
    <div style="page-break-after:always"></div>

     </div>
    </body>
```

Please note, I have to print multiple Labels with one PRINT command so I am using page-break-after:always, and within my Printer Settings I have set the "CUT-TYPE" to Partial Cut.